# Вызов метода java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! На днях озадачился вопросом: как можно сделать вызов метода через другую переменную? То есть, например, пользователь вводит строку с именем метода, а я его должен вызвать. Видел (вроде бы) что-то подобное в JavaScript при присвоении переменной функции. Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо.

Comment: В java это будет являться серьезным code smell, но возможно через рефлексию

Comment: В данном случае(если кол-во методов не очень большое) лучше создать enum, к каждому элементу которого привязан вызов соотв. метода. Сначала пытаетесь получить элемент enum'a через метода valueOf(), тем самым проверяете корректность ввода, а потом выполняете соотв. метод. Не стоит использовать рефлексию без реальной надобности

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью Reflection - http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Например, для класса с именем "my class", найдем метод "my method" с параметрами `parameterTypes`. И далее вызовем его для объекта `objectToInvokeOn` c параметрами `params`:

```
// Находим класс
Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
// Находим метод
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("method name", parameterTypes)
// Вызываем метод для объекта
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```

Можно и простой найти метод для известного объекта:

```
Method method = myObject.getClass().getMethod("method name", parameterTypes);
method.invoke(myObject, params);
```